# JSF multiple field validation NULLPointerException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, validation

```
<h:form id="form">
Username: <br/>
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{home.username}" required="true" >
<f:validator validatorId="loginValidator"></f:validator> 
<f:attribute name="passwordComponent" value="#{passwordComponent}" ></f:attribute>
</h:inputText>
<br/>
Password: <br />
<h:inputText id="password"  bindig="#{passwordComponent}" value="#{home.password}"  required="true"></h:inputText>
<br/>
<h:commandButton value="login" id="login" action="#{home.login}"></h:commandButton>
</h:form>



public class LoginValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
        throws ValidatorException {
    String username = (String)value;
    UIInput passwordInput = (UIInput)component.getAttributes().get("passwordComponent");
    String password = (String) passwordInput.getValue();

    if(username!="aa" || password!="aa"){
        passwordInput.setValid(false);
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage("Wrong username or password!"));
    }
}
```

}

at this line I get NuulPointerException:

String password = (String) passwordInput.getValue();

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spellings of the word "**binding**" is incorrect in following line.

```
<h:inputText id="password"  bindig="#{passwordComponent}"...
```

change **bindig** to **binding**.